# mean, nanmean and warning: Mean of empty slice

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

Say I construct three numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, 3])
c = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN])
```

Now I find that `np.mean` returns `nan` for both `b` and `c`:

```
>>> np.mean(a)
2.0
>>> np.mean(b)
nan
>>> np.mean(c)
nan
```

Since numpy 1.8 (released 20 April 2016), we've been blessed with [nanmean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), which ignores `nan` values:

```
>>> np.nanmean(a)
2.0
>>> np.nanmean(b)
3.0
>>> np.nanmean(c)
nan
C:\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py:598: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice", RuntimeWarning)
```

So, `nanmean` is great, but it has the odd and undesirable behaviour of raising a warning when the array has nothing **but** `nan` values.

How can I get the behaviour of `nanmean` without that warning?  I don't like warnings, and I don't like suppressing them manually.

Comment: why is the warning an issue?

Comment: I must admit, the warning makes no sense. One sensible behaviour is to consistently return `nan`; the other, to consistently raise an exception. A warning is such a meh response.

Comment: What's wrong with suppressing warnings? You don't have to do it wholesale - just suppress the warning where you know you might use `np.nanmean` on an array of all NaNs.

Comment: Also, you don't have to look to `nanmean` - you get the same silly thing with `np.mean([])`.

Comment: Your question actually contained the answer I seeked for the meaning of this warning.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I really can't see any good reason not to just suppress the warning.

The safest way would be to use the [`warnings.catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) context manager to suppress the warning only where you anticipate it occurring - that way you won't miss any additional `RuntimeWarnings` that might be unexpectedly raised in some other part of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import warnings

x = np.ones((1000, 1000)) * np.nan

# I expect to see RuntimeWarnings in this block
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
    foo = np.nanmean(x, axis=1)
```

@dawg's solution would also work, but ultimately any additional steps that you have to take in order to avoid computing `np.nanmean` on an array of all NaNs are going to incur some extra overhead that you could avoid by just suppressing the warning. Also your intent will be much more clearly reflected in the code.

Comment: This is a useless warning and there is no `seterr` for it like other errors

Comment: Are you sure that the only warning that might be raised here is this particular one? That is the reason for not suppressing warnings in general - what if this raises another warning (possibly in some future version) ?

Comment: Exactly, what @Mr_and_Mrs_D, this seems like a good way to cover up actual bugs in the code. Numpy should probably raise a specific warning that sub-classes RuntimeWarning.

Comment: I came here when I searched for this warning:
RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.

In my case it was due to finding the mean of an empty array. I should have paid attention to the warning as this results in a NaN value which caused me a lot of grief in model building, so the warning isn't simply supposed to be ignored.

Comment: OP clearly asks they dont want to suppressing warnings. Approches stated by @dawg are more approprate. Please consider deleting this answer.

Comment: `warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', message='Mean of empty slice')` seems safer, since it won't ignore other`RuntimeWarning`s that you haven't anticipated.

Comment: @Aaron's comment was particularly useful for shutting down this specific error, possibly globally if needed. I for one didn't realize you could specify a message to filter by!

Answer (score 26):

A `NaN` value is defined to not be equal to itself:

```
>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
False
>>> np.NaN == np.NaN
False
```

You can use a Python conditional and the property of a nan never being equal to itself to get this behavior:

```
>>> a = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN])
>>> b = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, 3])
>>> np.NaN if np.all(a!=a) else np.nanmean(a)
nan
>>> np.NaN if np.all(b!=b) else np.nanmean(b)
3.0
```

You can also do:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN])
b = np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN, 3])

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    try:
        x=np.nanmean(a)
    except RuntimeWarning:
        x=np.NaN    
print x
```

Comment: That works for one-dimensional numpy arrays.  Unfortunately in my actual use case I have multidimensional data and I'm taking the mean along one dimension.
e.g. `np.nanmean(np.array([[np.NaN], [3]]),1)`

Comment: Add appropriate slicing then. Also, `np.nanmean(np.array([[np.NaN], [3]]),1)` seems to work as expected...

Comment: Why use a `try`/`except` block? `np.nanmean(a)` will return `np.nan` anyway.

Comment: Just strikes me as more expected syntax to put this into a `try / except` block as other Python code would be for something that might be different than the normal return.

Comment: Besides, returning a scalar `np.nan` would be incorrect for `np.nanmean` along one axis of a multidimensional array containing only NaNs

Comment: dawg, I get the RuntimeWarning when I run `np.nanmean(np.array([[np.NaN], [3]]),1)`.  I'm using Python 3.4.  I think ali_m is right that the best thing is to catch this particular warning.

Comment: @dawg Why use the form `np.all(a != a)` which assumes everyone knows nan != nan when you could use the clearer `np.isnan(a).all()`?