# Why am I getting a 'hashable' error when combining two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames and I'm attempting to combine them as follows:

```
df3 = df1.combine(df2, np.mean)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.

I'm not sure I understand why I'm getting the message as by definition DataFrames are mutable?

I don't get an error if I switch to:

```
df3 = df1.combine(df2, np.minimum)
```

Is this something to do with me having `NaN` values in the two DataFrames? If it is then what would be the solution? Devise my own function to replicate `np.mean`?

**Updated:**

I just found `np.nanmean` but that gives the following error:

`TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.mean` takes one positional argument as the input array. So you cannot and should not do

```
 np.mean(series1, series2)
```

Since the command above will interpret `series2` as the second argument for `np.mean`, which is `axis`. But this argument is an integer and `python` try to convert `series2` into one, which triggers the error.

In stead, you should do this for mean:

```
np.mean([series1, series2])
```

In the other case, `np.minimum` is designed to do:

```
np.minimum(series1, series2)
```

and gives the minimum element-wise as expected.

---

**TLDR** For mean, you can just do:

```
df = (df + df2)/2
```

Comment: Thanks. ```np.mean([series1, series2])``` doesn't produce the right result because it is averaging the sum of each column. I want the average of each value and its equivalent value in the second DataFrame. ```df = (df + df2)/2``` gives the right result but can't handle the ```np.nan``` values. Any ideas? Replace all ```np.nan``` with zeros?

Comment: `np.mean([series1, series2], axis=0)` would do. Also `df.combine(df, lambda x,y: np.mean([x,y], axis=0))` would work.

Comment: Thanks. ```df.combine(df, lambda x,y: np.nanmean([x,y], axis=0))``` did the trick and accounted for the ```np.nan``` values. DataFrame is output correctly but I was getting a error when ```np.nanmean``` tried to average two ```np.nan``` values. This post here solved that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688168/mean-nanmean-and-warning-mean-of-empty-slice